# Find all JPG pathnames in HTML files and convert them into all lowercase

Tags: html, regex, batch-processing

I have a very basic understanding of regexp. I have searched and searched the internet for this.....

I have a linux server which only likes lowercase file names and I stupidly have image filenames in title case!

I want to batch find all jpg pathnames in my HTML files and convert them into all lowercase with Regex.

`My-File-Name1.jpg` needs to be `my-file-name1.jpg`

I think I need a regex expression to find them all, and another that replaces them converted into lowercase.

Any help?

EDIT

@Sniffer gave me the regex that gets the filename path.

In [notepad ++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) find and replace using regex. You can use

`([\w/-]+)\.jpe?g` to find image pathnames and

`: \L\1` to change to lowercase and using replace

`\U\2` to change to higher case using replace

I found the lower/uppercase regex here http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/ecb11904/

Comment: Do all these file names contains only alphabetical characters like a, b, c, etc ..

Comment: @Sniffer no they have dashes and numbers too "Queen-of-Hearts-1.jpg". I edited my question to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I would say use an HTML parser which is the best tool for the job here but since you only want jpg files then you might be able to find them all by using the following:

```
([\w/-]+)\.jpe?g
   ^
   |
   |
 As you can see I have added the forward slash / and the dash - to the
 character class, WARNING: the dash - should always be the last character in the
 class, keep that in mind if you have more special characters.
```

You will have to match this globally in your file.

As for the conversion, it can't be done using a regex. You will have to call an API that converts a string to lower case, and use it on the captured groub `$1`.

Comment: This only grabs the last section eg "-Card.jpg" instead of "img/Rider-Waite/13-Queen-of-Cups-Minor-Tarot-Card.jpg". Proberly my fault for not adding in the slashes for the file directories - sorry.

Comment: Fab! Thanks. I found that you can use a regex in notepad++ that will change the search results into lower case.

Comment: Yes! I am so happy Thanks @Sniffer :) You saved several hours/days of my life!